# Flutter Getx: initial value of obs variable set to null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Upon now I always use getx observable declarations like this:

```
var someString = ''.obs;
var someNumber = 0.obs;
```

and so on...

But what if some variables don't have an initial value at first, and I actually want them to be null and later change them?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For non null-safe (pre Dart 2.12), you can declare your observable variables like this:

```
final someVariable = Rx<Type>();
```

For example:

```
final someString = Rx<String>();
final someNumber = Rx<int>();
```

And for null-safety (Dart 2.12 or later), Just use `Rxn<Type>` instead of `Rx<Type>`.

For example:

```
final someString = Rxn<String>();
final someNumber = Rxn<int>();
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! One more follow-up though: could Rxn<Type> (>= Dart 2.12) affect flutter app performance?

Comment: Slightly. Because it needs checking unlike non-nullables (`Rx<Type>()`). But this shouldn't matter that much regarding your usecase.

Comment: You saved me so much mate

Comment: `Rx<LanguageData> kLanguage = Rx<LanguageData>();` I have a model class called LanguageData. I tried your solution but it gives the error `1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.` @S.M.JAHANGIR

Comment: 1 positional argument expected by 'Rx.new', but 0 found.
Try adding the missing argument.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have an initial value for your [Rx] value (at the first time), you need to use

```
final Rx<YourObject?> yourObject = (null as YourObject?).obs;
```

Or for more organizing your code, you can create a separate class, like this

```
class RxNullable<T> {
  Rx<T> setNull() => (null as T).obs;
}
```

and use:

```
final Rx<YourObject?> yourObject = RxNullable<YourObject?>().setNull()
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else does face this problem.

```
final Rx<YourObject?> yourObject = (null as YourObject?).obs;
```

will work.

but if there's any message that says "Unnecessary cast. Try removing the cast.", just add this comment

```
// ignore: unnecessary_cast
```

above the line, and then save.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it on class say a station class the code example is

```
 late Rx<Station?> station = Rx<Station?>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your observable variables like this for (dart 2.18 and above):

**Rx varName = (T()).obs;**

Answer (score 0):

Getx in flutter,
I search lot of time How class as observable

so fixed,
Like this ,

```
  Rx<HomeModel?> mainModel =HomeModel(content: []).obs;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another Best way is you can make your variable optional

> `final Rx<YourObject>? yourObject;`

then user obs when you declare your variable first time

> `yourObject.value = yourObject.obs;`

and use it by force wrap

> `var newObject = yourObject!;`

Comment: this way, the observed value will never be actually null. the observable will, instead